# Expected validator to return Promise or Observable async validator FormGroup angular 7

Tags: angular

Hope you're safe. I am using anuglar 7,I am validating the template name exist in db or not through aysnc validation api call. I am passing the async validator as an third argument but getting error when I input something on input field. Can anyone please help me out. I am searched lot of post but none of them help me. Thanks you

Problem --> when I input some value I am getting " ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable."

#Below is my create-table.component.ts file code :

```
       ngOnInit() {
          this.getProducts();
   
    this.table = new FormGroup({

        tableName: new FormControl ('',
        Validators.required
        ,this.customTableNameValidator.bind(this)
         ),
    });
}
```

## Here is the async function

```
                  customTableNameValidator() {
                    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
                     return this.dataService.templateDuplicate(control.value).pipe(
                         map((res) => {
                         console.log("result : ", res["message"]);
                         return res["message"] ? { templateExist: true } : null;
                      })
                    );
                  };
                 }
```

## Here is the service api call code .Here "res['message']" will return boolean value

```
              templateDuplicate(tableName: string): Observable<any> {
                 return this.http
                     .post<any>(this.appBaseUrl + "validate-template-name/" + tableName, null)
                     .pipe(
                      map((res) => {
                      console.log("Res : ", res["message"]);
                       return res["message"];
                      })
                  );
               }
```

## Below is the Html file element tag

```
                 <input class="form-control" formControlName="tableName"  />
```

## Below is the api response.I am taking "message" property value and returning it in the above code.

```
                  {
                    "statusMessage": null,
                    "filePath": null,
                    "message": true
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to see if it helps you

```
  customTableNameValidator() {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      return this.dataService.templateDuplicate(control.value).pipe(
        map((res:any) => {
          console.log("result : ", res["message"]);
          return res["message"] ? { templateExist: true } : null;
        })
      );
    };
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.table = new FormGroup({
      tableName: new FormControl ('',
       [ Validators.required, this.customTableNameValidator]
      ),
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Vue ang, thanks for looking into this issue. I made the changes suggest by you but no luck. What i see that , when I change the input value,  the function "customTableNameValidator()" is getting called but the api call is not getting called. I tried this function putting as third argument as well since it is an async validation but that also didn't work. Please help

Comment: Asynchronous validators should be used like this
```ts
  tableName: new FormControl ('',
       null, [ Validators.required, this.customTableNameValidator]
      ),
```

Comment: I have tried passing the async function inside an array but it didn't work out. Can you suggest any other option.

Comment: Angular11 is normal, sorry, maybe your version is too low, can I ask you what needs to be checked asynchronously